# Have the 8-column-wide div all the 12 columns if the 4-column-wide div is not exist with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I want is, if the the 4-column-wide section is not exist, means it's disabled server-side, the 8-column-wide section will have all the 12 columns.

```
$var = true; // sometimes false
<div class="row">
  <?php if ($var) echo '<div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>'; ?>
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
</div>
```

I know it can be get with another conditional statement in the 8-column-wide `div` *(see my current answer below)*, but is there a better way to get it with just a predefined class or else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that's coming from my mind:

```
$var = true; // sometimes false
<div class="row">
  <?php if ($var) echo '<div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>'; ?>
  <div class="col-md-<?php
    if ($var) :
      echo 8;
    else :
      echo 12;
    endif;
  ?>">.col-md-8</div>
</div>
```

Put another conditional `if` statement in the 8-column-wide `div`..

Comment: I will accept my answer temporarily until a valid answer _(if any)_ come!